# Operator Overloading to Construct Exception Message

Tags: c++, exception, operator-overloading, c++03

I am changing some code in a legacy code base. Inside this code there is an often repeated pattern that looks like the following:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << ...;
throw MyCustomException(ss.str());
```

Since I am modifying the code anyways I wanted to make something like the following:

```
throw MyCustomException() << ...;
```

effectively removing the need for the `std::stringstream`.

I found a solution:

```
struct MyCustomException: public std::runtime_error
{
    MyCustomException(const std::string& what_arg="")
    : std::runtime_error(what_arg)
    {
    }

#if 0
    template<typename T>
    friend
    MyCustomException operator<<(MyCustomException e, const T& obj)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << e.what();
        ss << obj;
        return MyCustomException(ss.str());
    }
#else
    template<typename T>
    MyCustomException operator<<(const T& obj)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << what();
        ss << obj;
        return MyCustomException(ss.str());
    }
#endif
};
```

Both solutions (`#if ... #endif`) work, but since everything is by value, a lot of copies of the exception object are created before it is thrown. Changing the signature to `MyCustomException& e` produces a ton of compile time errors (why?).

The whole problem is further complicated by the fact that I am bound to an old GCC revision that only supports C++03. So no fancy C++1[147] stuff here!

Is there a better way to make my desired functionality (`throw MyCustomException() << ...;`) work without the creation of the many temporary copies when throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

> [S]ince everything is by value, a lot of copies of the exception object are created before it is thrown

If exceptions are exceptional ([as they should](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Re-errors)), the run-time lost should not be something you care about. Furthermore, [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) might save your day. Profile and conclude.

That being said, you could remove half of the alleged copies by taking a const-ref:

```
struct MyCustomException: public std::runtime_error
{
    MyCustomException(const std::string& what_arg="")
    : std::runtime_error(what_arg)
    {}

    template<typename T>
    friend
    MyCustomException operator<<(MyCustomException const& e, T const& obj)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << e.what();
        ss << obj;
        return MyCustomException(ss.str());
    }
};
```

Comment: strange that I didn't think about the `const` reference thing :/ Unfortunately I still get the same amount of copies as before with `friend ... const MyCustomException&`. That's maybe even stranger.